# In Romans 11:11 who is made jealous of whom?

Tags: greek, romans, grammar, referent-identification, syntax

> YLT Rom 11:11 I say, then, Did they stumble that they might fall? let
>   it not be! but by their fall the salvation is to the nations, **to
>   arouse them to jealousy**;

Do the fallen Jews make the gentiles jealous or do the newly saved gentiles make the Jews jealous?

Comment: How would jealous gentiles fit into the context?

Comment: @PerryWebb  This might be a greek question. I'll add a tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the syntax is clear:

> ἀλλὰ τῷ **αὐτῶν** παραπτώματι ἡ σωτηρία τοῖς **ἔθνεσιν** εἰς τὸ παραζηλῶσαι **αὐτούς**.
>
> but by **their** (*masc*) trespass the salvation [came to] the **gentiles** (*neut*) in order to provoke **them** (*masc*) to jealousy

As you can see, the masculine referent is the Jews ("Israel", from v. 7); thus, αὐτούς refers to the Jews. The distinct neuter masculine accusative pronoun αὐτά would be used if the antecedent were the neuter noun ἔθνη (gentiles).